# Three alternating row colours in a table with multirow

Tags: tables, color, tabularx, multirow, rowcolor

I have an horribly complex LaTeX table which I try to make a bit more readable.

I would like to use three different row colours, starting at the batch size column.

It is very difficult to do so, because every row consists of two rows (please ignore those zero values, they will soon change to meaningful values) and in the beginning, they are merged in packs of three.

The code is the following:

```
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{Modell} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\multirow{2}{*}{Batch size}} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{Learning rate} \\ \cline{3-6}
                        & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                            & 0.05    & 0.10   & 0.15   & 0.20   \\ \hline
\hline
\cellcolor{white}\multirow{6}{*}{Multilingual Flair}    & \multirow{2}{*}{16}        & 0.7319    & 0.7705    & 0.7901    & \textit{0.8316}   \\             
                        &                            & ±0.0      & ±0.0      & ±0.0      & ±0.0      \\ \cline{2-6} 
                        & \multirow{2}{*}{32}        & 0.631     & 0.681     & 0.7658    & 0.7747    \\             
                        &                            & ±0.0      & ±0.0      & ±0.0      & ±0.0      \\ \cline{2-6} 
                        & \multirow{2}{*}{64}        & 0.5919    & 0.6628    & 0.6676    & 0.7105    \\             
                        &                            & ±0.0      & ±0.0      & ±0.0      & ±0.0      \\ \hline      
 
\multirow{6}{*}{BERT}   & \multirow{2}{*}{16}        & 0.8113    & 0.8215    & 0.8279    & 0.8307    \\             
                        &                            & ±0.0      & ±0.0      & ±0.0      & ±0.0      \\ \cline{2-6} 
                        & \multirow{2}{*}{32}        & 0.7918    & 0.8236    & \textbf{0.8338}   & 0.8286    \\             
                        &                            & ±0.0      & ±0.0      & ±0.0      & ±0.0      \\ \cline{2-6} 
                        & \multirow{2}{*}{64}        & 0.7495    & 0.8008    & 0.8027    & 0.8128    \\             
                        &                            & ±0.0      & ±0.0      & ±0.0      & ±0.0      \\ \hline      
 
\multirow{6}{*}{XLM-RoBERTa}    & \multirow{2}{*}{16}        & 0.5972    & 0.5939    & 0.6351    & 0.6162    \\             
                        &                            & ±0.0      & ±0.0      & ±0.0      & ±0.0      \\ \cline{2-6} 
                        & \multirow{2}{*}{32}        & 0.5855    & 0.5929    & \textit{0.6364}   & 0.6057    \\             
                        &                            & ±0.0      & ±0.0      & ±0.0      & ±0.0      \\ \cline{2-6} 
                        & \multirow{2}{*}{64}        & 0.5641    & 0.5943    & 0.5989    & 0.6177    \\             
                        &                            & ±0.0      & ±0.0      & ±0.0      & ±0.0      \\ \hline      
 
\end{tabular}
```

At the moment, it looks like that:
[image]

However, I would love to have it looking that way (with other colours for sure):
[image]
Are there any nice ideas out there how to do so?
The `\rowcolors{1}{grey!25}{white}` command seems to work only with two colours

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `\rowcolor` for each row and a different placement of the `\multirow` commands, you can achieve the following output. Personally, I'd prefer a different colorless approach that also removes almost all lines in the table. I have also included the code for this approach as well:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[table,svgnames]{xcolor}

% Just used in the second example table:
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\normalsize}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\robustify\bfseries
\robustify\itshape


\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{Modell} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\multirow{2}{*}{Batch size}} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{Learning rate} \\ \cline{3-6}
                        & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                            & 0.05    & 0.10   & 0.15   & 0.20   \\ \hline
\hline
\rowcolor{LightYellow}\cellcolor{white}                                    &                      & 0.7319  & 0.7705  & 0.7901          & \textit{0.8316}   \\             
\rowcolor{LightYellow}\cellcolor{white}                                    & \multirow{-2}{*}{16} & ±0.0    & ±0.0    & ±0.0            & ±0.0      \\ \cline{2-6} 
\rowcolor{LightPink}\cellcolor{white}                                      &                      & 0.631   & 0.681   & 0.7658          & 0.7747    \\             
\rowcolor{LightPink}\cellcolor{white}                                      & \multirow{-2}{*}{32} & ±0.0    & ±0.0    & ±0.0            & ±0.0      \\ \cline{2-6} 
\rowcolor{LightCyan}\cellcolor{white}                                      &                      & 0.5919  & 0.6628  & 0.6676          & 0.7105    \\             
\rowcolor{LightCyan}\cellcolor{white}\multirow{-6}{*}{Multilingual Flair}  & \multirow{-2}{*}{64} & ±0.0    & ±0.0    & ±0.0            & ±0.0      \\ 
\hline      
 
\rowcolor{LightYellow}\cellcolor{white}                                    &                      & 0.8113  & 0.8215  & 0.8279          & 0.8307    \\             
\rowcolor{LightYellow}\cellcolor{white}                                    & \multirow{-2}{*}{16} & ±0.0    & ±0.0    & ±0.0            & ±0.0      \\ \cline{2-6} 
\rowcolor{LightPink}\cellcolor{white}                                      &                      & 0.7918  & 0.8236  & \textbf{0.8338}  & 0.8286   \\             
\rowcolor{LightPink}\cellcolor{white}                                      & \multirow{-2}{*}{32} & ±0.0    & ±0.0    & ±0.0            & ±0.0      \\ \cline{2-6} 
\rowcolor{LightCyan}\cellcolor{white}                                      &                      & 0.7495  & 0.8008  & 0.8027          & 0.8128    \\             
\rowcolor{LightCyan}\cellcolor{white}\multirow{-6}{*}{BERT}                & \multirow{-2}{*}{64} & ±0.0    & ±0.0    & ±0.0            & ±0.0      \\ 
\hline      
 
\rowcolor{LightYellow}\cellcolor{white}                                    &                      & 0.5972  & 0.5939  & 0.6351          & 0.6162    \\             
\rowcolor{LightYellow}\cellcolor{white}                                    & \multirow{-2}{*}{16} & ±0.0    & ±0.0    & ±0.0            & ±0.0      \\ \cline{2-6} 
\rowcolor{LightPink}\cellcolor{white}                                      &                      & 0.5855  & 0.5929  & \textit{0.6364} & 0.6057    \\             
\rowcolor{LightPink}\cellcolor{white}                                      & \multirow{-2}{*}{32} & ±0.0    & ±0.0    & ±0.0            & ±0.0      \\ \cline{2-6} 
\rowcolor{LightCyan}\cellcolor{white}                                      &                      & 0.5641  & 0.5943  & 0.5989          & 0.6177    \\             
\rowcolor{LightCyan}\cellcolor{white} \multirow{-6}{*}{XLM-RoBERTa}        & \multirow{-2}{*}{64} & ±0.0    & ±0.0    & ±0.0            & ±0.0      \\ 
\hline      
\end{tabular}
\bigskip

\sisetup{separate-uncertainty, table-format=1.4(5), detect-all}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\noindent
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}lcSSSS}
\toprule
\thead{Modell} & \thead{Batch\\ size} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\thead{Learning rate}}              \\ 
\cmidrule{3-6}
                    &     & {0.05}    & {0.10}     & {0.15}           & {0.20}                 \\ 
\midrule
Multilingual Flair  & 16  & 0.7319(1) & 0.7705(22) & 0.7901(333)      & \itshape 0.8316(4444)  \\             
                    & 32  & 0.631     & 0.681      & 0.7658           & 0.7747                 \\             
                    & 64  & 0.5919    & 0.6628     & 0.6676           & 0.7105                 \\             
\addlinespace    
BERT                & 16  & 0.8113    & 0.8215     & 0.8279           & 0.8307                 \\             
                    & 32  & 0.7918    & 0.8236     & \bfseries 0.8338 & 0.8286                 \\             
                    & 64  & 0.7495    & 0.8008     & 0.8027           & 0.8128                 \\             
\addlinespace      
XLM-RoBERTa         & 16   & 0.5972    & 0.5939    & 0.6351           & 0.6162                 \\             
                    & 32   & 0.5855    & 0.5929    & \itshape 0.6364  & 0.6057                 \\             
                    & 64   & 0.5641    & 0.5943    & 0.5989           & 0.6177                 \\             
\bottomrule      
\end{tabular*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is wonderful, thank you so much for your effort! I do have two questions about it:
1) Is there anything I need to reset after the table is finished? (like that one with tablecolsep), I want to use other tables in the document as well

Comment: 2) Can I adjust the column width? It seems like it isn't enough width and the numbers overlap when I insert it. I might need to have a look why this is the case

Comment: @DORpapst: There is not really the need to reset anything. Just place a `{` right before the `\sisetup...` and a `}` right after `\end{tabular*}` and all setting are kept local to this specific table. If you place your table in a `table` environment (to get it to float), there settings are local to the corresponding `table` environment, automatically.

Comment: The table width automatically adapts to the textwidth. Since you didn't provide information about the documentclass and package you use, I assumed some settings. To make sure the numbers don't overlap, you could either decrease the margin size or adapt the font size within the table accordingly. For more specifi advice, please provide the necessary settings.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, it works now. The latter question was due to me copying it wrong ;)

Answer (score 2):

A solution without `multirow`, based on `collcell` and `stackengine`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[table, svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow, hhline}
\usepackage{collcell}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{$\collectcell\Vectorstack}l<{\endcollectcell$}}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\setstackEOL{\nl}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|>{\cellcolor{white}}c|>{\cellcolor{white}}c|*{4}{L|}}
\hline
&& \multicolumn{4}{c|}{Learning rate} \\
\hhline{|~|~|----|}
\multirow{-2}{*}{Modell} & \multirow{-2}{*}{Batch size} & 0.05 & 0.10 & 0.15 & 0.20 \\
\hline\hline
\rowcolor{Wheat} & 16 & 0.7319\nl \pm 0.0 & 0.7705\nl \pm 0.0 & 0.7901\nl \pm 0.0 & \textit{0.8316}\nl \pm 0.0 \\
\hhline{|~|-----|}
\rowcolor{LavenderBlush}Multilingual Flair & 32 & 0.631\nl \pm 0.0 & 0.681\nl \pm 0.0 & 0.7658\nl \pm 0.0 & 0.7747\nl \pm 0.0 \\
\hhline{|~|-----|}
\rowcolor{PowderBlue!50} & 64 & 0.5919\nl \pm 0.0 & 0.6628\nl \pm 0.0 & 0.6676\nl \pm 0.0 & 0.7105\nl \pm 0.0 \\
 \hline
\rowcolor{Wheat} & 16 & 0.8113 \nl \pm 0.0 & 0.8215\nl \pm 0.0 & 0.8279 \nl \pm 0.0 & 0.8307 \nl \pm 0.0 \\% \cline{2-6}
\hhline{|~|-----|}
\rowcolor{LavenderBlush}BERT & 32 & 0.7918\nl \pm 0.0 & 0.8236\nl \pm 0.0 & \textbf{0.8338}\nl \pm 0.0 & 0.8286\nl \pm 0.0 \\
\hhline{|~|-----|}
\rowcolor{PowderBlue!50} & 64 & 0.7495\nl \pm 0.0 & 0.8008\nl \pm 0.0 & 0.8027\nl \p 0.0 & 0.8128\nl \pm 0.0 \\
\hline
\rowcolor{Wheat} & 16 & 0.5972\nl \pm 0.0 & 0.5939\nl \pm 0.0 & 0.6351\nl \pm 0.0 & 0.6162\nl \pm 0.0 \\
\hhline{|~|-----|}
\rowcolor{LavenderBlush}XLM-RoBERTa & 32 & 0.5855 \nl \pm 0.0 & 0.5929\nl \pm 0.0 & \textit{0.6364}\nl \pm 0.0 & 0.6057 \nl \pm 0.0 \\
\hhline{|~|-----|}
\rowcolor{PowderBlue!50} & 64 & 0.5641\nl \pm 0.0 & 0.5943\nl \pm 0.0 & 0.5989\nl \pm 0.0 & 0.6177\nl \pm 0.0 \\
 \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It seems like you also solved my problem with those two merged rows per batch. One more nice solution!

Answer (score 2):

You can easily do that table with `nicematrix`.

The output will be perfect in all the PDF viewers, at all levels of zoom (you won't have rules which seem to vanish).

However, you need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{ccllll}%
 [ 
   vlines ,
   code-before = 
    \rectanglecolor{yellow!15}{3-2}{4-6}
    \rectanglecolor{red!15}{5-2}{6-6}
    \rectanglecolor{blue!15}{7-2}{8-6}
    \rectanglecolor{yellow!15}{9-2}{10-6}
    \rectanglecolor{red!15}{11-2}{12-6}
    \rectanglecolor{blue!15}{13-2}{14-6}
    \rectanglecolor{yellow!15}{15-2}{16-6}
    \rectanglecolor{red!15}{17-2}{18-6}
    \rectanglecolor{blue!15}{19-2}{20-6}
 ]
\Hline
\Block{2-1}{Modell} & \Block{2-1}{Batch size} & \Block[c]{1-4}{Learning rate} \\ \Hline
                        &                            & 0.05    & 0.10   & 0.15   & 0.20   \\ 
\Hline
\Block{6-1}{Multilingual Flair}    & \Block{2-1}{16}        & 0.7319    & 0.7705    & 0.7901    & \textit{0.8316}   \\             
                        &                            & ±0.0      & ±0.0      & ±0.0      & ±0.0      \\ \Hline
                        & \Block{2-1}{32}        & 0.631     & 0.681     & 0.7658    & 0.7747    \\             
                        &                            & ±0.0      & ±0.0      & ±0.0      & ±0.0      \\ \Hline
                        & \Block{2-1}{64}        & 0.5919    & 0.6628    & 0.6676    & 0.7105    \\             
                        &                            & ±0.0      & ±0.0      & ±0.0      & ±0.0      \\ \Hline      
\Block{6-1}{BERT}   & \Block{2-1}{16}        & 0.8113    & 0.8215    & 0.8279    & 0.8307    \\             
                        &                            & ±0.0      & ±0.0      & ±0.0      & ±0.0      \\ \Hline
                        & \Block{2-1}{32}        & 0.7918    & 0.8236    & \textbf{0.8338}   & 0.8286    \\             
                        &                            & ±0.0      & ±0.0      & ±0.0      & ±0.0      \\ \Hline
                        & \Block{2-1}{64}        & 0.7495    & 0.8008    & 0.8027    & 0.8128    \\             
                        &                            & ±0.0      & ±0.0      & ±0.0      & ±0.0      \\ \Hline
 
\Block{6-1}{XLM-RoBERTa}    & \Block{2-1}{16}        & 0.5972    & 0.5939    & 0.6351    & 0.6162    \\             
                        &                            & ±0.0      & ±0.0      & ±0.0      & ±0.0      \\ \Hline
                        & \Block{2-1}{32}        & 0.5855    & 0.5929    & \textit{0.6364}   & 0.6057    \\             
                        &                            & ±0.0      & ±0.0      & ±0.0      & ±0.0      \\ \Hline
                        & \Block{2-1}{64}        & 0.5641    & 0.5943    & 0.5989    & 0.6177    \\             
                        &                            & ±0.0      & ±0.0      & ±0.0      & ±0.0      \\ \Hline
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: Thanks for your answer as well. Is it possible to put that in a floating environment and label/caption it? I have never worked with tabular. But it looks good!

Comment: You can place an environment `{NiceTabular}` in a `{table}` exactly as you would do with an standard environment `{tabular}`.

Comment: Really? That’s amazing. Thank you so much for your answer, I wish a wonderful evening

Comment: Is there are reason why you write \Hline with capital h? Does that make a difference?

Comment: With `\Hline` (of `nicematrix`), the horizontal rule is not drawn in the blocks (created by `\Block`).